# Copy 2d Character Array inAanother 2d Array Using STRCPY

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort, c-strings

I am trying to copy a 2d character array into another 2d character array using the string function strcpy but it's giving me the error of access violation. I don't know what is it that I am doing wrong. I am posting the code and error can somebody tell me what is it that I am doing wrong

```
int searching(char *name[],char * namesearched,int size)
{
    int count =0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = count;
    for(;start<=end;)
    {
        int mid = (start + end)/2;
        if(strcmp(namesearched,name[mid])==0)
        {
        return mid;
        }
        else if(strcmp(namesearched,name[mid])==1)
        {
         end=mid -1; 
        }
        else if(strcmp(namesearched,name[mid])==-1)
        {

            start = mid +1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void sorting(char **name,char ** meaning,int count)
{
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<count; j++)
        {
            char tempname[100];
            char tempmeaning[100];
            if(strcmp(name[j-1],name[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(tempname,name[j]);
                //strcpy(name[j],tempname);
                strcpy(name[j-1],name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j],name[j-1]);
                strcpy(name[j-1],tempname);

                strcpy(tempmeaning,meaning[j]);
                strcpy(meaning[j],meaning[j-1]);
                strcpy(meaning[j-1], tempmeaning);
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int size=60;
    int count=0;
    char namesearched[100];
    cout << "Enter the name to be searched: ";
    cin.getline(namesearched , 100);
    char** name= new char * [size];
    char** meaning = new char * [size];
    for(int i=0;i < size ; i++)
    {
        name[i]= new char [100];
        meaning[i]= new char[100];
        count ++;
    }
    name[0] = "Journalist";
    name[1] = "Blister";
    name[2] = "List";
    name[3] = "Listen";
    name[4] = "Novelist";
    name[5] = "Song";
    name[6] = "Eat";
    name[7] = "West";
    name[8] = "Idealist";
    name[9] = "Industry";
    name[10] = "Legalist";
    name[11] = "Write";
    name[12] = "Medal";
    name[13] = "Nation";
    name[14] = "Accident";
    name[15] = "Nest";
    name[16] = "Bird";
    name[17] = "Animal";
    name[18] = "Lion";//wrong
    name[19] = "Pigeon";
    name[20] = "Real";
    name[21] = "Accept";
    name[22] = "Ability";
    name[23] = "Bald";
    name[24] = "Backbite";
    name[25] = "Wakeful";
    name[26] = "Absolute";
    name[27] = "Wail";
    name[28] = "Abiding";
    name[29] = "Unacceptable";
    name[30] = "Tacker";
    name[31] = "Vain";//wrong
    name[32] = "Abolish";
    name[33] = "Taking";
    name[34] = "Unarmed";
    name[35] = "Habit";
    name[36] = "Notus";
    name[37] = "Impecle";
    name[38] = "Accelerate";
    name[39] = "Agony";
    name[40] = "Sulk";
    name[41] = "Nowise";
    name[42] = "Hypocrisy";
    name[43] = "Nape";
    name[44] = "Eccentric";
    name[45] = "Naturally";
    name[46] = "Gratitude";
    name[47] = "Mesmerizing";
    name[48] = "Epic";
    name[49] = "Abstain";
    name[50] = "Enactment";
    name[51] = "Hammock";
    name[52] = "Nodal";
    name[53] = "Laborious";
    name[54] = "Nonverbal";
    name[55] = "Haggle";
    name[56] = "Notorious";
    name[57] = "Lagger";
    name[58] = "Pathetic";
    name[59] = "Norms";


    meaning[0] = "Sahaafi";
    meaning[1] = "Chaala";
    meaning[2] = "Fehrist";
    meaning[3] = "Sunna";
    meaning[4] = "Naval Nigaar";
    meaning[5] = "Ganna";
    meaning[6] = "Khanna";
    meaning[7] = "Maghrib";
    meaning[8] = "Tadawuri";
    meaning[9] = "Sannat";
    meaning[10] = "Zabta Parast";
    meaning[11] = "Likhna";
    meaning[12] = "Tangha";
    meaning[13] = "Qoom";
    meaning[14] = "Hadsa";
    meaning[15] = "Ghonsla";
    meaning[16] = "Parinda";
    meaning[17] = "Janwar";
    meaning[18] = "Shair";
    meaning[19] = "Kabootar";
    meaning[20] = "Haqeekat";
    meaning[21] = "Qabool";
    meaning[22] = "Kabliyat";
    meaning[23] = "Ganja";
    meaning[24] = "Ghebat Karna";
    meaning[25] = "Jagta";
    meaning[26] = "Bikul";
    meaning[27] = "Gham Karna";
    meaning[28] = "Mustakil";
    meaning[29] = "NaGawar";
    meaning[30] = "Jorna Wala";
    meaning[31] = "Gari";
    meaning[32] = "Rad kar dena";
    meaning[33] = "Dil-chasp";
    meaning[34] = "Nehatta";
    meaning[35] = "Addat";
    meaning[36] = "Dakni hawwa";
    meaning[37] = "Rokna";
    meaning[38] = "Taiz karna";
    meaning[39] = "Sakht Takleef";
    meaning[40] = "Roth Jana";
    meaning[41] = "Hargiz Nahi";
    meaning[42] = "Naffaq";
    meaning[43] = "Mankaa";
    meaning[44] = "Sanki";
    meaning[45] = "Fitratan";
    meaning[46] = "Tashakur";
    meaning[47] = "Mashoor Karna";
    meaning[48] = "Razmiya";
    meaning[49] = "Baaz Rakhna";
    meaning[50] = "Nifaaz";
    meaning[51] = "Jholay ki tarhan ka Bichona";
    meaning[52] = "Gutheela";
    meaning[53] = "Mehnat Talab";
    meaning[54] = "Ghair Lafzey";
    meaning[55] = "Takrar Karna";
    meaning[56] = "Badnam";
    meaning[57] = "Ahista Chalnay walla";
    meaning[58] = "Intehai afsoos naak baat";
    meaning[59] = "Mayar";

    int mid;
    sorting( name , meaning , count);
    int mid = searching(name,namesearched,count); 
    if( mid == -1 )
    {
        char ** tempname = new char* [60];
        char ** tempmeaning = new char*[60];
        if(count == size)
        {
            int increase =(10 * size)/100;
            size = increase + size;
            for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
            {
                tempname[i] = new char [100];
                tempmeaning[i]= new char [100];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<count ; i++)
            {                
                strcpy(tempname[i],name[i]);
                strcpy(tempmeaning[i],meaning[i]);
            }
        }
        strcpy(tempname[count] , namesearched);
        cin >> tempmeaning[count];
        count ++;

        sorting( tempname , tempmeaning , count);

        for (int i =0;i < count ;i++)
        {
            delete [] name[i];
            delete [] meaning[i];
        }
        //delete [] name;
        //delete [] meaning;
        name = tempmeaning;
        meaning = tempmeaning;
        tempmeaning = NULL ;
        tempname = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout <<"The meaning of " << namesearched << " is: " << meaning[mid] << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

> Access violation writing location 0x001fbe5c.

The value of **count** and **size** is 60

One thing more strcpy works on this line `strcpy(tempname , name[j])` but when it encounter this line `strcpy(name[j] , name[j-1])` it throws me the error of access violation

Comment: Please add to your post values of "count" and "i".

Comment: @FozanGardezi the error is clearly in your input data somwhere. Your code seems to not crash with valid input: http://ideone.com/it8Qzv . So you should probably look at this and edit your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterT it works with 1d array but it startss crashing when I introduce 2d array in the code. `strcpy(tempname,name[j]);` Here tempname is a 1d array and name is a 2d array. I copy array infront of name[j] in tempname and it works but when I try to do this it crashes `strcpy(name[j],name[j-1]);`

Comment: @FozanGardezi I can't understand what you're saying, just show us a complete example that reproduces the problem

Comment: This is tagged `C++` but it's not C++ (at least what most people around here consider it), it should be retagged to `C`. (With true C++, this would be a oneliner, probably)

Comment: @PeterT I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function declaration

```
void sorting(char *name[],char *meaning[],int size,int count);
```

does not deal with two-dimensional arrays.

For example if you have two-dimensional arrays like this

```
char name[60][100];
char meaning[60][100];
```

then the function declaration will look like

```
void sorting( char name[60][100], char meaning[60][100], size_t count );
```

or

```
void sorting( char name[][100], char meaning[][100], size_t count );
```

or

```
void sorting( char ( *name )[100], char ( *meaning )[100], size_t count );
```

and the value of the argument for the third parameter should be equal to 60.

As for your function declaration then for example this parameter `char *name[]`
has type of incomplete one-dimensional array of pointers of type `char *` that is adjusted to type `char **`. And if the corresponding argument is an array of pointers to string literals then the function has undefined behavior because you may not change string literals.

So it seems you are processing the arrays incorrectly that is their definitions do not correspond to the logic of the function code.

Also parameter `size` is not used in the function.

Thus your code simply wrong initially.

Take into account that the condition in this if statement

```
if(strcmp(name[j-1],name[j]))
```

should look either like

```
if ( strcmp( name[j-1], name[j] ) > 0 )
```

if you want to sort the arrays in the ascending order or like

```
if ( strcmp( name[j-1], name[j] ) < 0 )
```

if you want to sort the arrays in the descending order.

**EDIT:** After you appended your question then it is seen that 1) there are memory leaks because the pointers that initially pointed to the allocated memory are reassigned with addresses of string literals and 2) you are trying to change string literals that are immutable.

Instead of for example

```
name[0] = "Journalist";
```

you have to write

```
strcpy( name[0], "Journalist" );
```

Comment: I tried it. and I wrote the functions prototype like this `void sorting(char **name,char ** meaning,int count)` but it still is throwing the same error. I tried it with the solution you provided and it's also giving me the same erro

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2d char arrays, just array of strings. So you can do it without using strcpy. Something like:

```
void sorting(char *name[],char *meaning[], int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < count - i; j++)
        {
            char *tempname;
            char *tempmeaning;
            if(strcmp(name[j-1],name[j]) > 0)
            {
                tempname = name[j];
                name[j] = name[j-1];
                name[j-1] = tempname;

                tempmeaning = meaning[j];
                meaning[j] = meaning[j-1];
                meaning[j-1] = tempmeaning;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`char *name[]` is an array of pointers to char. Pointer to char can be interpreted like a pointer to the first element of array of chars (to string). So if you want to swap two strings in array, you just need to swap pointers to that strings.

Comment: I know about that but I can't understand why isn't the strcpy function working

Comment: `strcpy` doesn't work because `name[i]` is a pointer to constant. And you try to modify constant which leads to an error.

Comment: but then when I copy it index by index then why does copies it if it's constant

Comment: You can't do `char *g = "foo"; g[0]  = 'b'` But you can do `char *g = "foo"; g  = "bar"`